# Entity framework getting record by exact date and time

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In entity framework I am querying a view and getting records which match a certain id and datetime. I want to get records which have an exact both date and time as effDate.

```
 var deals = context.Table
    .Where(d => d.DealID == DealId && d.EffectiveDate == effDate)
    .ToList();
```

This is the view in database.

[image]

When the `dealId is 2013-00188` and `effDate is shown above 2017/03/08 09:55:39` the query does not return any record however if you look at the database you can see their is a record which matches both id and effDate. Even when I add the nano second to effDate it doesnt bring any record.

To top it of this query bring back records in sql 2012 and sql 2014 however sql 2016 it doesn't!

I have included the sql generated by entity framework as you can see the date is not in the correct format and inside by database the Effective date is stored as a datetime not a datetime2. I need to make sure the date has the correct format.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[DealID] AS [DealID], 
    [Extent1].[Item] AS [Item], 
    [Extent1].[EffectiveDate] AS [EffectiveDate], 
    [Extent1].[ChargeID] AS [ChargeID], 
    [Extent1].[SegmentCost] AS [SegmentCost], 
    [Extent1].[CustomSolutionsCost] AS [CustomSolutionsCost], 
    [Extent1].[ItemChargeIndicator] AS [ItemChargeIndicator], 
    [Extent1].[LandOCost] AS [LandOCost], 
    [Extent1].[TreatRate] AS [TreatRate], 
    [Extent1].[SegmentGrossProfit] AS [SegmentGrossProfit], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerSpecificPrice] AS [CustomerSpecificPrice], 
    [Extent1].[MultipleCustSpecific] AS [MultipleCustSpecific], 
    [Extent1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], 
    [Extent1].[DataSource] AS [DataSource], 
    [Extent1].[BOMKeyField] AS [BOMKeyField], 
    [Extent1].[ItemDescription] AS [ItemDescription], 
    [Extent1].[AdditiveType] AS [AdditiveType], 
    [Extent1].[AdditiveTypeDescription] AS [AdditiveTypeDescription], 
    [Extent1].[SpecificGravity] AS [SpecificGravity], 
    [Extent1].[BOMSource] AS [BOMSource], 
    [Extent1].[CostDate] AS [CostDate], 
    [Extent1].[CostSource] AS [CostSource], 
    [Extent1].[PriceDate] AS [PriceDate], 
    [Extent1].[PriceSource] AS [PriceSource], 
    [Extent1].[Vendor] AS [Vendor], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate]
    FROM [dbo].[vwDealBOM] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[DealID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[EffectiveDate] = @p__linq__1)


-- p__linq__0: '2013-00188' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)

-- p__linq__1: '08/03/2017 09:55:39' (Type = DateTime2)
```

Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, especially when it is such a trivial amount of code to begin with. Copy/paste the text of the code in to the question. That said you should open Sql Server Profiler and see what the complete execution statement with parameter values is that is being executed. Begin there and see if that offers any clues.

Comment: I cant use sql profiler since I am working against a db on a network. I have logged the ef generated sql to console and it look fine.

Comment: If you have the logged query you should post it in the question along with the passed parameter values.

Answer (score -1):

**effDate** and **EffectiveDate** millisecond values are not equal. **effDate** millisecond value is 0 but you are looking for a record with 607.

Comment: `Even when I add the nano second to effDate it doesnt bring any record.`